# How do I paste values of a column in a table into a cell in text format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to code a rudimentary macro to have data from a Ctrl+A/C'd webpage into lines easily copied into a word document. One of the bits of data exist as a table and the number of rows can vary. There's data after the table so I cant use lastrow and my code doesn't work. I'd really appreciate some help on this.

```
Sub Fill()

Dim wsi As Worksheet
Dim wscpy As Worksheet

Set wsi = Sheets("Raw Data Info")
Set wsa = Sheets("Raw Data Accts")
Set wscpy = Sheets("Copy to fund details")

wscpy.Range("A1").Value = "Name: " & wsi.Range("A36").Value
wscpy.Range("A2").Value = "D.O.B.: " & wsi.Range("B92").Value
wscpy.Range("A3").Value = "Address: " & wsi.Range("C42") & ", " & wsi.Range("C44") & ", " & wsi.Range("C45") & " " & wsi.Range("C47") & " " & wsi.Range("C46")

'...blah blah...

wscpy.Range("A13").Value = "Gross Monthly Income: " & wsi.Range("B89")
wscpy.Range("A14").Value = "Accounts held: "
'This is the bit I have problems with
wscpy.Range("A15").Value = wsa.Range("A43", wsa.Range("A43").End(xlDown))
wscpy.Range("A16").Value = wsa.Range("A43", wsa.Range("A43").End(xlDown))


End Sub
```

So the accounts table basically looks like this

https://gyazo.com/6355ebfe0ebdaf4f0396fc1e632dd34d

How would I be able to code to list out the data (account and number) in their corresponding cells in wscpy?

As always, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, what errors are you seeing with the code you have there? Is the text below the table consistent in any way - can you imagine a test to find it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get Last row from wsa.

```
Sub Fill()

Dim wsi As Worksheet
Dim wscpy As Worksheet
Dim LastRow as Long

Set wsi = Sheets("Raw Data Info")
Set wsa = Sheets("Raw Data Accts")
Set wscpy = Sheets("Copy to fund details")

wscpy.Range("A1").Value = "Name: " & wsi.Range("A36").Value
wscpy.Range("A2").Value = "D.O.B.: " & wsi.Range("B92").Value
wscpy.Range("A3").Value = "Address: " & wsi.Range("C42") & ", " & wsi.Range("C44") & ", " & wsi.Range("C45") & " " & wsi.Range("C47") & " " & wsi.Range("C46")

'...blah blah...

wscpy.Range("A13").Value = "Gross Monthly Income: " & wsi.Range("B89")
wscpy.Range("A14").Value = "Accounts held: "

'you can get LastRow here
'LastRow = wsa.Range("A43").End(xlDown).Row
'or would be better if you use this code
LastRow = wsa.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
wscpy.Range("A15:A" & LastRow -28 ).Value = wsa.Range("A43:A" & LastRow).Value
'I am not sure why you need this
'wscpy.Range("A16:A" & LastRow -27").Value = wsa.Range("A43:A" & LastRow).Value


End Sub
```

Hope this help.

Thanks